# tabfocus on select box

Tags: jquery, css, less, jquery-select2

I'm trying to show the focused state of a select box in an `html` form. When I tab through the elements of the forms, which are pretty much all `input type="text"` elements, the focus works as I specified in the css, but when the tab focus gets to the `select` box, there isn't a visual indication that the `select` box is focus, but if I hit tab again, the focus moves to the next element.

Below is the `less` code I'm using:

```
input,
textarea {
  .box-shadow(inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075));
  @transition: border linear .2s, box-shadow linear .2s;
  .transition(@transition);
}
input:focus,
select:focus,
textarea:focus {
  border-color: rgba(82,168,236,.8);
  outline: 0;
  outline: thin dotted \9; /* IE6-9 */
  .box-shadow(~"inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,.6)");
}
input.warning:focus,
textarea:focus {
  border-color: @redMid;
  outline: 0;
  outline: thin dotted \9; /* IE6-9 */
  .box-shadow(~"inset 0 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 0px rgba(82,168,236,.6)");
}
input[type="file"]:focus,
input[type="radio"]:focus,
input[type="checkbox"]:focus
select:focus {
  .tab-focus();
  .box-shadow(none); // override for file inputs
}
```

Also, I'm using the custom select boxes from [Igor Vaynberg](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/).

Does anyone know why the select boxes aren't getting the focus styling that the other elements are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem - the issue was with the with the `tabIndex` on the generated `div` that contains the select. I modified the following code in the `select2.js`:

```
createContainer: function () {


    var container = $(document.createElement("div")).attr({
                "class": "select2-container",
                "tabIndex": "0"
            }).html([
                "<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='return false;' class='select2-choice' tabindex='-1'>",
                "   <span class='select2-chosen'>&nbsp;</span><abbr class='select2-search-choice-close'></abbr>",
                "   <span class='select2-arrow'><b></b></span>",
                "</a>",
                "<input class='select2-focusser select2-offscreen' type='text' tabindex='-1'/>",
                "<div class='select2-drop select2-display-none'>",
                "   <div class='select2-search'>",
                "       <input type='text' autocomplete='off' autocorrect='off' autocapitalize='off' spellcheck='false' class='select2-input'/>",
                "   </div>",
                "   <ul class='select2-results'>",
                "   </ul>",
                "</div>"].join(""));

            return container;
        },
```

and added the `tabIndex` to the attributes of the container.

Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you could be overriding the select focus style with this block at the end:

```
input[type="file"]:focus,
input[type="radio"]:focus,
input[type="checkbox"]:focus
select:focus {
 .tab-focus();
 .box-shadow(none); // override for file inputs
}
```

You also seem to be missing a comma before the select:focus part anyway which could be causing problems.

Comment: I tried adding a comma and removing the select:focus to make sure it wasn't getting overwritten and it still didn't work.

Comment: Are you using a particular browser? I tried this... [link](http://jsfiddle.net/RMF6Z/1/) and it seems to work. The only thing I changed was the border size to make it more obvious.

Comment: I'm using Chrome, and your link worked, but when I put the css in my code, it didn't work in my project. Do you think it has to do with the fact that I'm using this library: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/ for my select2 boxes?

Comment: There's probably a good chance yes. Have you used Chrome's inspector to see what styles are applied/overwritten?